# Re-run user Start-up programs (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a number of shortcuts and executable files in:

`C:\Users\<Profile>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

These are run automatically on login, as per default Windows behaviour.

Most of these are autohotkey scripts, which can sometimes stop working over time (e.g. after putting the PC to sleep).

Is there a command or Task Scheduler job that can be used to re-launch all these programs, as if they were executed in the login sequence? I suppose it is possible to execute everything in the folder via a [manual script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074668/batch-script-that-executes-all-programs-in-a-directory), though I'm curious if something already exists for Start-up programs specifically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing other special for this purpose. Try a batch script:

```
@echo off
cd "%Userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
for %%a in (*) do (
  start "%%~fa"
)
```